# Using images at lower resolution

Tags: html, css

So I have JPEG with a resolution of 180x180px. Is it a bad idea to display it with a width and height of 32px? Should I resize it?

Comment: It probably won't matter for an image as small as that. But in general it'd be better to have a separate file for a thumbnail as bigger files mean slower loading times!

Comment: not really.. that image size is almost irrelevant in terms of bandwidth. sometimes we even make the size of an image 2x larger on purpose so that it looks better on mobile, as they tend to zoom in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it will loose a lot of it meaning, just think about how much of the image is being removed, you can do it, but personally i would have an image specifically for 32x32 and a separate one for 180x180